# Building data structures at compile time with template-metaprogramming, constexpr or macros

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, macros, template-meta-programming

I want to optimize a little program/library I'm writing and since 2 weeks I'm somewhat stuck and now wondering if what I had in mind is even possible like that.
(Please be gentle I don't have very much experience in meta-programming.)

My goal is of course to have certain computations be done by the compiler, so that the programmer - hopefully - only has to edit code at one point in the program and have the compiler "create" all the boilerplate. I do have a reasonably good idea how to do what i want with macros, but it is wished that I do it with templates if possible.

**My goal is:**
Lets say I have a class that a using programmer can derive from. There he can have multiple incoming and outgoing datatypes that I want to register somehow so that the base class can do it's operations on them.

```
class my_own_multiply : function_base {
  in<int> a;
  in<float> b;
  out<double> c;

  // ["..."] // other content of the class that actually does something but is irrelevant
  register_ins<a, b> ins_of_function; // example meta-function calls
  register_outs<c> outs_of_function;
}
```

The meta-code I have up till now is this: (but it's not yet working/complete)

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct register_ins {
  const std::array<std::unique_ptr<in_type_erasured>, sizeof...(Ts)> ins;

  constexpr std::array<std::unique_ptr<in_type_erasured>, sizeof...(Ts)>
    build_ins_array() {
      std::array<std::unique_ptr<in_type_erasured>, sizeof...(Ts)> ins_build;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); ++i) {
        ins_build[i] = std::make_unique<in_type_erasured>();
      }
    return ins_build;
  }

  constexpr register_ins() : ins(build_ins_array()) {
  }

  template <typename T>
  T getValueOf(unsigned int in_nr) {
    return ins[in_nr]->getValue();
  }
};
```

As you may see, I want to call my meta-template-code with a variable number of ins. (Variable in the sense that the programmer can put however many he likes in there, but they won't change at runtime so they can be "baked" in at compile time)

The meta-code is supposed to be creating an array, that is of the length of the number of ins and is initialized so that every field points to the original in in the my_own_multiply class. Basically giving him an indexable data structure that will always have the correct size. And that I could access from the function_base class to use all ins for certain functions which are also iterable making things convenient for me.

Now I have looked into how one might do that, but I now am getting the feeling that I might not really be allowed to "create" this array at compile time in a fashion that allows me to still have the ins a and b be non static and non const so that I can mutate them. From my side they wouldn't have to be const anyway, but my compiler seems to not like them to be free. The only thing I need const is the array with the pointers. But using constexpr possibly "makes" me make them const?

Okay, I will clarify what I don't get:
When I'm trying to create an "instance" of my meta-stuff-structure then it fails because it expects all kinds of const, constexpr and so on. But I don't want them since I need to be able to mutate most of those variables. I only need this meta-stuff to create an array of the correct size already at compile time. But I don't want to sacrifice having to make everything static and const in order to achieve this. So is this even possible under these kinds of terms?

Comment: I've got a real problem trying to understand what you want. I suspect you might be better of learning first about other metaprogramming libraries, e.g. Boost. That said, the "type erasured" stuff just looks wrong. Why are you bothering with that? I'm expecting to see `std::tuple`, not `std::array`.

Comment: The type erasure stuff is only scematic for now so i'm not surprised that it seems fishy. Important is the part where i'm creating a data structure that i can access from the base class in the end.
What would you need a tuple for? Why are you expecting that?

Comment: Which version of C++ can you use? If it is C++14 or later, functions with `constexpr` can provide compile-time computations which are easy to read and maintain (replacing some of the old-style template metaprogramming hacks). If you are interested, I can prepare an example as answer.

Comment: Are those examples tailored somewhat to my problem? If so i would definitely like to see them. :)

Comment: I am not sure, but the paragraph where you describe your desire to "mutate" something that should be `constexpr` later made me think that an example like [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292620/2615118) could help. Note that inside `multiply`, it looks as if we mutate `ret`. On the other hand, the caller can assign to a `constexpr` (given `constexpr` arguments).

Comment: @Andimanos - I don't undestand what do you want `cont`, `constexpr` and modifiable. Anyway, It's surely possible do a `std::array` that is `constexp` but I don't think it's possible for a `std::array` of smart pointers (`std::make_unique` isn't `constexpr`).

Comment: @Andimanos - OT: just for fun (not suggested); if I'm not wrong, the constructor of `register_ins` can simply be written as `register_ins() :  ins { (Ts{}, std::make_unique<in_type_erasured>())... }` (if all `Ts` are POD).

Answer (score 0):

I do not get all the things you have in mind (also regarding that `std::unique_ptr` in your example), but maybe this helps:

Starting from C++14 (or C++11, but that is strictly limited) you may write `constexpr` functions which can be evaluated at compile-time. As a precondition (in simple words), all arguments "passed by the caller" must be `constexpr`. If you want to enforce that the compiler replaces that "call" by the result of a compile-time computation, you must assign the result to a `constexpr`.

Writing usual functions (just with `constexpr` added) allows to write code which is simple to read. Moreover, you can use the same code for both: compile-time computations and run-time computations.

C++17 example (similar things are possible in C++14, although some stuff from `std` is just missing the `constexpr` qualifier):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/154e2dfcc41fb6c7

```
#include <cassert>

#include <array>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T, N> multiply(
  const std::array<T, N>& a,
  const std::array<T, N>& b
) {
// may be evaluated in `constexpr` or in non-`constexpr` context

// ... in simple man's words this means:
// inside this function, `a` and `b` are not `constexpr`
// but the return can be used as `constexpr` if all arguments are `constexpr` for the "caller"
  std::array<T, N> ret{};
  for(size_t n=0; n<N; ++n) ret[n] = a[n] * b[n];
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  {// compile-time evaluation is possible if the input data is `constexpr`
    constexpr auto a = std::array{2, 4, 6};
    constexpr auto b = std::array{1, 2, 3};
    constexpr auto c = multiply(a, b);// assigning to a `constexpr` guarantees compile-time evaluation

    static_assert(c[0] == 2);
    static_assert(c[1] == 8);
    static_assert(c[2] == 18);
  }
  {// for run-time data, the same function can be used
    auto a = std::array{2, 4, 6};
    auto b = std::array{1, 2, 3};
    auto c = multiply(a, b);

    assert(c[0] == 2);
    assert(c[1] == 8);
    assert(c[2] == 18);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this is not the solution i was looking for it still helped me find what i was missing to find my own solution. Thank you for that. Should i still mark it as the right answer?

Comment: @Andimanos: I am not sure. If your solution is neat and simple to explain you could answer your own question and accept your answer. If that is not worth the effort then accepting my answer would at least indicate to others that your problem is solved.